# How to parse a csv file that contains 15 million lines of data in php

Tags: php, csv, fgetcsv

I have a script which parses the CSV file and start verifying the emails. this works fine for 1000 lines. but on 15 million lines it shows memory exhausted error. the file size is 400MB. any suggestions? how to parse and verify them?

Server Specs: Core i7 with 32GB of Ram

```
function parse_csv($file_name, $delimeter=',') {
  $header = false;
  $row_count = 0;
  $data = [];

  //  clear any previous results
  reset_parse_csv();

  // parse
  $file = fopen($file_name, 'r');
  while (!feof($file)) {
    $row = fgetcsv($file, 0, $delimeter);
    if ($row == [NULL] || $row === FALSE) { continue; }
    if (!$header) {
      $header = $row;
    } else {
      $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
      $row_count++;
    }
  }
  fclose($file);

  return ['data' => $data, 'row_count' => $row_count];

}

function reset_parse_csv() {
  $header = false;
  $row_count = 0;
  $data = [];    
}
```

Comment: When you do `$data[]` you are keeping a copy of the data - this will eventually use all of the memory.  You will probably have to validate each row as you read it.

Comment: @NigelRen okay, also do multi-threading or slicing will help?

Comment: If you can split the file easily enough you can split the task, but CSV's can be a pain as they can be variable length lines.

Comment: the bigger file, bigger `$data` memory usage. Why in the hell you need to return `$data`? CSV file is already formated data.

Comment: @felipsmartins to verify emails from the CSV. so what I'm getting is I should not save the copy in the `data` variable.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pushing a large dataset (file lines, etc.) into array increases memory usage and this is directly proportional to the number of items handling.
So the bigger file, the bigger memory usage - in this case.

So instead of collecting the data into array, better *process it in place:*

```
$file = fopen($file_name, 'r');
while (!feof($file)) {
    $row = fgetcsv($file, 0, $delimeter);
    if ($row == [NULL] || $row === FALSE) { continue; }
    if (!$header) {
        $header = $row;
    } else {
        // do whatever's intended to do with row
        // instead of $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
        do_something($row);
    }
}
```

The major difference here is:
you do not get (from memory) and consume all data **at once**. You get items **on demand** (like a stream) and process it instead, **one item at time**. It has huge impact on memory usage.

However, in case the actual workload cannot be easily moved inside the loop (for example, it's a function that expects an array to be processed) you can *move the processing elsewhere* while keeping the memory footprint low. For this, you can use a [generator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.php).

Reading the PHP doc it fits very well for your case (emphasis mine):

> *A generator allows you to write code that uses foreach to iterate over a set of data **without needing to build an array in memory**, which
> may cause you to **exceed a memory limit**, or require a considerable
> amount of processing time to generate.*

Something like this:

```php
function csv_read($filename, $delimeter=',')
{
    $header = [];
    $row = 0;
    # tip: dont do that every time calling csv_read(), pass handle as param instead ;)
    $handle = fopen($filename, "r"); 

    if ($handle === false) {
        return false;
    }

    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, $delimeter)) !== false) {

        if (0 == $row) {
            $header = $data;
        } else {
            # on demand usage
            yield array_combine($header, $data);
        }

        $row++;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

And then:

```
$generator = csv_read('rdu-weather-history.csv', ';');

do_stuff_with_array($generator);
```

Here, `$generator` variable do not hold all data **at once**. On the one hand, it behaves much like an array, and can be used inside `foreach()` statement. On the other hand, it acts like a stream and reads **one item at time**.

---

*P.S.: The CSV file above has taken from:* https://data.townofcary.org/api/v2/catalog/datasets/rdu-weather-history/exports/csv

Comment: Why not put the `do_something($item);` in where the `yield` is?

Answer (score 2):

It is not necessary to write a generator function. The [SplFileObject](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splfileobject.php) also works fine.

```
$fileObj = new SplFileObject($file);

$fileObj->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV 
  | SplFileObject::SKIP_EMPTY 
  | SplFileObject::READ_AHEAD 
  | SplFileObject::DROP_NEW_LINE
);
$fileObj->setCsvControl(';');

foreach($fileObj as $row){
  //do something 
}
```

I tried that with the file "rdu-weather-history.csv" (> 500KB). memory_get_peak_usage() returned the value 424k after the foreach loop. The values ​​must be processed line by line.
If a 2-dimensional array is created, the storage space required for the example increases to more as 8 Mbytes.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could possibly attempt, is a Bulk Import to MySQL which may give you a better platform to work from once it's imported.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/user/data.csv' INTO TABLE CSVImport; where CSVimport columns match your CSV.
```

Bit of a left field suggestion, but depending on what your use case is can be a better way to parse massive datasets.